# How to fix PHP error: "Call to undefined function posix_strerror()"

Tags: php

The [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-strerror.php) describes the command `posix_strerror()` which is the analog to the C function `strerror()`:

> posix_strerror (PHP 4 >= 4.2.0, PHP 5, PHP 7) — Retrieve the system error message associated with the
>   given errno

However, calling this function generates error on my installation.

Sample code:

```
for ($i = 13; $i < 25; $i++)
{
    print "Errno $i : ";
    $s = posix_strerror($i);
    print "$s\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Errno 13 : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function posix_strerror() in /mnt/swdevel/Pelican/source_build/xfiles/junk.php on line 8
```

How can I enable this feature in PHP?  An internet search turns up pretty much nothing at all regarding this function.

**System Info**

```
Linux 4.4.211-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 23 08:25:59 EST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

php --version
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 08:42:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: is this your dev environment or production?

Comment: Same behavior both dev and production